# Shortest code to reverse array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, reverse

I need to find the shortest code for reversing an array and at the moment I have this:

```
weirdReverse=a=>a.sort(()=>1)
```

This is a codewars challenge and the length of this is 29 bytes. I need to have a length <=28 so I need to remove 1 byte and I can't change this part:

```
weirdReverse=a=>a
```

And I can't use `reverse()`.

Comment: How is sort order determined, here?  Couldn't you just leave out the `()=>1`?

Comment: Sorry im dumb , i need to reverse it i just look on sort() and i write i need to sort it , description is changed now

Comment: [`array.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) .. am I missing something??

Comment: didnt write it too ... i can't use reverse()

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can golf one byte off your anonymous arrow function by specifying an unused parameter instead of `()` to indicate no named parameters, bringing the total down to 28 bytes:

```
weirdReverse=a=>a.sort(_=>1)
```

Comment: Bro you are great , i didn't know about that

Comment: I just dont understand why i always get -1 when i create a topic , its sad :(

Comment: @Mariusz I haven't looked at your other questions, but this one barely qualifies as on-topic, and the answer is not going to be useful to anyone finding this on google, so there's no value-added for Stack Overflow to have this question on their site. I just happen to be an active participant on [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42091/patrick-roberts), so I knew the answer to this.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a named parameter instead of braces, like so:

`weirdReverse=a=>a.sort(b=>1)`

Comment: Thanks you both good to know i dont need to use () and i can change it to something different